# Using parameter map to pass data to controller

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

im using the new scheduler and I do not know how to pass the parameters from making an appointment to a controller to update my database. I think it has to do with the parameterMap but even if i change that to hold data or something how would i call it in the controller also. So theres two questions here. How can i get it to hold data and how can i pass the data to the controller.

```
parameterMap: function (options, operation, data) {
                            if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                return {
                                    models: kendo.stringify(options.models),
                                    value:data
                                };
                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the ASP.NET MVC tab > controller.cs: 
http://demos.kendoui.com/web/scheduler/index.html

```
public virtual JsonResult Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, TaskViewModel task)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            taskService.Insert(task, ModelState);
        }

        return Json(new[] { task }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
```

Looks like all of the data is in the model that you are passing into the controller action (kendo handles that part), so whichever way you have your database set up, all of the passed in data should be in the 'task' object.

Comment: the thing is i am using the html version of kendo and not the mvc one. I forgot to mention that